# Make Pandoc write LaTex commands from html `<cite>` tags in plain text

Tags: pandoc

I am trying to modify some code that allows one to compile code in a project directory that may take many formats, e.g., HTML, LaTex, markdown, using Pandoc (well, Pypandoc). I have some code in an HTML file that looks like this:

```
<h1 data-label="850151" class="ltx_title_section">A heading</h1><h2 data-label="367935" class="ltx_title_subsection">Another heading</h2><div><cite class="ltx_cite raw v1">\cite{ebert_epidemiology_2013}</cite></div><div>Figure <span class="au-ref raw v1">\ref{286335}</span></div><div></div>
```

This is the LaTex output.

```
...
\section{A heading}\label{a-heading}

\subsection{Another heading}\label{another-heading}

\textbackslash{}cite\{ebert\_epidemiology\_2013\}

Figure {\textbackslash{}ref\{286335\}}
...
```

The desired output is, of course

```
...
\section{A heading}\label{a-heading}

\subsection{Another heading}\label{another-heading}

\cite{ebert_epidemiology_2013}

\ref{286335}
...
```

I think if I could get Pandoc to strip the `<cite>` tags and write the citation command as plain text, that would work. I know Pandoc filters are a thing, but I'm not sure if that's what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can usee a [filter](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html) to strip the cite tags.

If you use `pandoc -f html+raw_html -t native`, you see that `<cite>bar</cite>`  are rendered to:

```
RawInline (Format "html") "<cite>",Str "bar",RawInline (Format "html") "</cite>"
```

So the filter should look something like:

```lua
function RawInline(elem)
  if elem.format == "html"
    return {}
  else
    return elem
end
```

Comment: As raw LaTeX is embedded into plain text, it might also help to re-interpret strings as LaTeX with a filter like this: `function Str (s) return pandoc.read(s.text, 'latex').blocks[1].content end`

Comment: I'm having trouble getting rid of `("",["au-ref","raw","v1"],[])` from the AST form of my original input.

Comment: It seems like there isn't an obvious (to me) way of getting rid of the `<span>` tags.